# Moving a Site Collection from SharePoint 2010 Foundation to SharePoint Server 2010

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, import

Is it possible to move a Site Collection from SharePoint 2010 Foundation to SharePoint Enterprise Server 2010.

I tried import/export using PowerShell and get an "Access is Denied" error on import.

```
[10/11/2011 1:44:21 PM] Start Time: 10/11/2011 1:44:21 PM.
[10/11/2011 1:44:21 PM] Progress: Initializing Import.
[10/11/2011 1:44:21 PM] FatalError: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
[10/11/2011 1:44:21 PM] Debug:    at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.GetSiteFlags(String bstrUrl)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite.get_ReadOnly()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.SPImport.InitializeImport()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.SPImport.Run()
[10/11/2011 1:44:21 PM] Progress: Import did not complete.
[10/11/2011 1:44:21 PM] Finish Time: 10/11/2011 1:44:21 PM.
[10/11/2011 1:44:21 PM] Duration: 00:00:00
[10/11/2011 1:44:21 PM] Finished with 0 warnings.
[10/11/2011 1:44:21 PM] Finished with 1 errors.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Technically, you have foundation in both cases.  Server "bolts" onto foundation.

These errors are common. For the sake of stating the obvious, you need to ensure the account you are using are properly privileged.  Open the site you are importing too and ensure the account you are using is a site collection administrator.

Additionally ensure you are running your Powershell environment with elevated privileges (i.e. Run as Administrator).

You can also attempt to use the -force parameter.

Comment: Correct, I was running the command under the wrong username. I needed to be running PowerShell under the Farm Administrator account. User privileges are incredibly challenging to understand and manage. I also needed to ensure that the site template was the same, although I had read that the Blank template was required. In this case I went from Team Site to Team Site.

Answer (score 1):

1) do a SPsite-backup in powershell to backup your site collection.

2) Provision (create) an application on the new server

3) restore the site collection to the application using restore-spsite

more info: [powershell syntax](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee748617.aspx)